# Concating in Lua using ; issue

Tags: linux, lua, concatenation

I can't concate when using a ';'. The following yeilds nothing in the below dump.txt:

```
returnString = returnString..Data[1]..","..Data[2]..";"
```

but if I do this, the data is placed inside dump.txt:

```
returnString = returnString..Data[1]..","..Data[2].."."
```

This is under Lua 5.2 in an embedded Linux OS. Does anyone know why the first doesn't work? Is this related to something I'm doing wrong from a code perspective or does this point towards an OS issue? I'm using this command to view the variables output:

```
 os.execute("echo "..returnString.." >>/tmp/dump.txt")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Compile error? Runtime error? Unexpected output?

Comment: Edited question for clarity to this comment.

Comment: See [my new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824905/how-good-is-using-q-in-lua-to-escape-shell-arguments) about solving this using `("echo %q"):format(arg)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> os.execute("echo "..returnString.." >>/tmp/dump.txt")

This translates into the command line:

```
echo x,y; >> /tmp/dump.txt
```

Can you see why that wouldn't work?