# How good is using %q in Lua to escape shell arguments?

Tags: shell, lua

Let's say we need to pass some argument to a shell command. (Let's assume a Bourne compatible shell.)

For example, let's say we want to print the string `He said "It's a boy"; sure` using echo(1).

Naturally, we can't do it this way:

```lua
s = [[He said "It's a boy"; sure]]
os.execute("echo " .. s)
```

But the following works fine:

```lua
s = [[He said "It's a boy"; sure]]
os.execute(("echo %q"):format(s))
```

My question: Do you think using %q to quote shell arguments is good enough?

I already know that `%q` isn't quite good if our argument includes a newline (it would get converted to slash+newline, which would mean that the shell would see no character; but at least it won't break the command). So that's one case against us. Are there any other cases where `%q` will fail us?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the reference manual for 5.1:

> the string is written between double quotes, and all double quotes, newlines, embedded zeros, and backslashes in the string are correctly escaped when written

Assuming this is correct, those are the only characters that will be escaped. In your case, there are special characters recognized by the shell, such as `;`, not in this list, so this would not escape it. But `%q` worked because it encloses the string with quotes so the `;` got hidden. Also, this is meant to generate a string that can be read by Lua. So adding an escape char to quotes, backslashes etc is not necessarily what you need for the command shell to understand your command. I think it is difficult to say for sure whether `%q` will always do what you want, for any shell.

Answer (score 11):

**No**, using `%q` is not good enough.  Dollar signs and backticks are *not* escaped, which can be abused to expose the contents of environment variables, or worse, execute arbitrary commands.